# Issue with Authorized.net with Magento2.2.5

Tags: magento2, checkout, orders, error, authorize.net

I am using Magento2.2.5 and payment gateway on my site is Authorized.net
I created a sandbox account of Authorized.net and put the required information in the admin panel.

Having Following issues:

1. The order is created with cancel status.
2. I received this mail as a merchant: https://prnt.sc/lusbbw , Where Transaction Id and Auth Code is 0

3.When Checkout Order created in the backend but no success page or error on the checkout page, Everything is displaying as they are and the cart is cleared.

4. Got this error in Exception log:  `main.CRITICAL: Please enter a transaction ID to authorize this payment. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): Please enter a transaction ID to authorize this payment. at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-authorizenet/Model/Directpost.php:654)"} []`
5. Even I tried with sandbox gateway URL By replacing Production as below:

**Sandbox URLs:**
https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll - gateway

https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api - transaction details

**Production URLs:**
https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll - gateway

https://api.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api - transaction details

but nothing helps.

6. Payment Log:

```
main.DEBUG: array (   'response' =>    array (
    'x_response_code' => '1',
    'x_response_reason_code' => '1',
    'x_response_reason_text' => '(TESTMODE) This transaction has been approved.',
    'x_avs_code' => 'P',
    'x_auth_code' => '000000',
    'x_trans_id' => '0',
    'x_method' => 'CC',
    'x_card_type' => 'Visa',
    'x_account_number' => 'XXXX1111',
    'x_first_name' => 'Neha',
    'x_last_name' => 'Vyas',
    'x_company' => '',
    'x_address' => '695  Atha Drive',
    'x_city' => 'New Orleans',
    'x_state' => 'North Carolina',
    'x_zip' => '70122',
    'x_country' => 'US',
    'x_phone' => '504-919-7848',
    'x_fax' => '',
    'x_email' => 'nehav23@mailinator.com',
    'x_invoice_num' => '000000021',
    'x_description' => '',
    'x_type' => 'auth_capture',
    'x_cust_id' => '',
    'x_ship_to_first_name' => 'Neha',
    'x_ship_to_last_name' => 'Vyas',
    'x_ship_to_company' => '',
    'x_ship_to_address' => '695  Atha Drive',
    'x_ship_to_city' => 'New Orleans',
    'x_ship_to_state' => 'North Carolina',
    'x_ship_to_zip' => '70122',
    'x_ship_to_country' => 'US',
    'x_amount' => '23.00',
    'x_tax' => '0.00',
    'x_duty' => '0.00',
    'x_freight' => '20.00',
    'x_tax_exempt' => 'FALSE',
    'x_po_num' => '',
    'x_MD5_Hash' => '30A3673E1EF476628D99886A87683A17',
    'x_SHA2_Hash' => '',
    'x_cvv2_resp_code' => '',
    'x_cavv_response' => '',
    'x_test_request' => 'true',
    'controller_action_name' => 'directpost_payment',
    'is_secure' => '1',   ), ) [] []
```

Suggestion how to fix it.

Comment: For sandbox environment the `Test Mode` should be disabled, it used only for production testing not for sandbox environment. Also, Authorize.net integration doesn't work on a local environment. Your Magento instance should be available from "public" Internet.

Comment: @jonijones, You mean Setting should be like these 2: https://prnt.sc/lwd64e and https://prnt.sc/lwd8q4, Send me screen-shots if I am getting you wrong.

Comment: The `Live Mode` in Authorize.net sandbox account should be enabled, not the `Test Mode`. Magento configuration is correct.

Comment: I changed but it is showing this: https://prnt.sc/lwgzvu

Answer (score 0):

you can use live URL and set live into test mode.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Its not working. I tried this: https://prnt.sc/lwex1n with https://prnt.sc/lwexno. And its reverse https://prnt.sc/lwfgxq with https://prnt.sc/lwfh1n